# How to generate a uniqueID

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I am working on a project in which we store students' information using a registration form that is created using JSP. Now I want here that each student should have a uniqueID. How can I do that?

I want ID to be the combination of first name,last-name and some digits(alphanumeric ID). Is there any way to do this? This ID generation can be done on database side or in the java? Each time I store the information from the JSP page there should be a ID automatically generated for each entry and that too stored in DB.

I am using mysql as Database.

Comment: In my point of view best approach is try to use current timestamp along with first name and last name, which is always unique.

Comment: How are you persisting the data. If using an RDBMS then use a sequence/identity/… as unique identifier. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: i think you should use UUID. Which is simple and easy

Answer (score 1):

Try to combine your student details with uuid following is how to generate uuid in java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "");
    System.out.println("uuid = " + uuid);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and after your answer I go through this method and what I have seen in case of UUID is that it will generate a ID something like : 44e128a5-ac7a-4c9a-be4c-224b6bf81b20 but I think that will be difficult to remmember because I want that my user can login my app using the generated ID.

Comment: @user8411341 What about combining arrival date and time (upto seconds ) with guest name ?

Answer (score 1):

When you get the input data call this function

```
public String generateID(String f_name,String l_name) {
    String uniqueID = f_name.trim()+l_name.trim()+UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    return uniqueID;
}
```

and set the value from this function to db

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyMMddHHmmssSS").format(new Date());
```

date variable contains unique datetime value and then add your first name and last name with date like

```
String userId=firstName+lastName+date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Although there are ways like include timestamp, random numbers or UUID generation but still there are chances (although negligible) of getting the same id in a highly concurrent environment. I would recommend to add DB generated sequence number in addition to other things like timestamp etc. somewhere in the unique key to make sure you are always getting unique id.